# Evenly distribute scent in a collaborative diffusion matrix

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I am trying to implement a collaborative diffusion behaviour for the first time and I am stuck with a problem. I understand how to make obstacles not diffusing scents and how to dampen scent for other friendly agents if one of them already pursues it. What I cannot understand is how do I make scents to evenly distribute in the matrix. It seems to me that every way of iterating in the matrix, determines the scent to distribute faster and better in the tiles I check later in the iteration. I mean if I iterate from i to maxRows and j to maxCols and then I apply the diffusion equation in every tile, on the 'north' and 'west' side of the goal I will have only one tile with the correct potential, whereas in the 'east' and 'south' side I will have more of them since their neighbours already have an assigned potential. How can I make the values distribute evenly? A double iteration from both extremities of the matrix and them combining the result seems like a memory-eater, as do a goal-oriented approach, since if I try to start from the goals and work around them I will have to execute the calculations for every goal and every tile with assigned potential, which means that I will have to do it for 4^(turn since starter diffusion)*nrOfGoals more every turn, which seems inefficient in a large matrix with a lot of goals.

My question is how can I evenly distribute the values in the matrix in an efficient way. I'm using the AiChallenge Ants, if that helps in any way!

I thank you in anticipation and I'm sorry for the grammar mistakes I've made in this post.

Comment: To add to my game of life answer, I found some old documents on optimizing the game of life engine behind the scenes. http://www.nondot.org/sabre/Mirrored/GraphicsProgrammingBlackBook/gpbb17.pdf and http://www.nondot.org/sabre/Mirrored/GraphicsProgrammingBlackBook/gpbb18.pdf go into a lot of details.

I've been using these types of out-of-box thinking to implement very large diffusion map(s) on GPGPUs efficiently. 

What I am saying, is that you don't necessarily want to throw away what you have now - It isn't 'wrong' in so much that it might the first steps toward a different solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a better solution, but the easiest way to do it is to use something similar to how a simple implementation of the game of life is done.

You have two buffers.  One has the current "generation" of scent (and if you are doing multitasking, can be locked so only readers can look at it)... and another has the next generation of sent being calculated.  You only "mix" scents from the current generation.

Once you are done, you swap the two buffers by simply changing the pointers / references.

Another way to think about it would be to have all the tiles calculate their new sent by asking their neighbors and averaging. When asked by their neighbors what their scent level is, they report their pre-calculated values from the previous pass.  The new sent is only locked in once everyone has finished calculating.